# HTTP Error 500.19 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I created and deployed a pretty simple WCF Service. but when accessing it from IE, I get this :

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Description: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration  
data for the page is invalid. 

Error Code: 0x80070005 

Notification: BeginRequest 

Module: IIS Web Core 

Requested URL: http://localhost:80/ProductsService/ProductsService.svc 

Physical Path: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ProductsService\ProductsService\ProductsService.svc 

Logon User: Not yet determined 

Logon Method: Not yet determined 

Handler: Not yet determined 

Config Error: Cannot read configuration file 

Config File: \\?\C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects \ProductsService\ProductsService\web.config 

Config Source:    -1: 
                   0:
```

```
More Information... This error occurs when there is a problem reading the  configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs  may contain more information about what caused this error.
```

here is the content of my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="AdventureWorksConnection" />
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AdventureWorksConnection" connectionString="Database=AdventureWorks;    Server=(localhost)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Products.ProductsService">
        <endpoint address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="Products.IProductsService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I believe your IIS doesn't know about the .svc files yet - see this blog post for more info and explanation how to fix that: rogerpence.com/blog/?p=280

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like your service exposes no metadata exchange at all - you'll need to add at least the serviceMetadata behavior so that clients can inquire about the service's metadata, and if you want to be able to retrieve that using a browser, you'll also need to enable the httpGet on that serviceMetadata behavior:.

Extend your web.config like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Metadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Products.ProductsService" behaviorConfiguration="Metadata">
        <endpoint address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        contract="Products.IProductsService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Marc

Comment: I think it's security related because I gave access to my Service folder to user IIS_USRS and now, I'm getting another error :

 HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
Description: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) map policy that is configured on the Web server. The page you requested has a file name extension that is not recognized, and is not allowed.

Comment: I believe your IIS doesn't know about the .svc files yet - see this blog post for more info and explanation how to fix that: http://rogerpence.com/blog/?p=280

Answer (score 2):

Check the web application folder permission and make sure the following users and groups are included with full permissions: \IIS_IUSRS and \IUSR.

Answer (score 0):

for the 404.3 error have you taken a look at this [link](http://adefwebserver.com/Dotnetnukehelp/Misc/Configuring_WCF.htm)?

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry what I meant is 404.3.. must be a typo error.. I'll edit my post. Thanks.