# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I am migrating my application from cloud sites to dedicated server. The dedicated server is running on Windows 2008 server 64 bit with IIS 7. My application pool in the new server is in integrated mode.

I have a default.htm page as the start page and it works fine. I cannot access any other pages and encountering the error "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error"

The configuration source showing as error is as follows.

```
{system.webServer}
   68:       {httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/errorpage-404.asp" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL"}
   69:          {remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" /}
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Error Message:**
*"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."*

**Solution:**
One way you can get this error is from having multiple copies of the solution, each of them using the same port number. You can usually solve this problem by exiting all instances of Visual Studio, then restarting the project you're working on. If that doesn't work, try changing the port number. Right click on the project file and then click properties. Select the Web tab and then change the port number in the Project Url text box.

For more information please visit: [Advanced Entity Framework 6 Scenarios for an MVC 5 Web Application (12 of 12)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application)