# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm moving a pretty basic site from Win 2003 to Win 2008 R2.  The site is getting the error listed below.  How can I diagnose this?  I moved a number of other sites between these 2 servers & this is the only on that is receiving this error.

I've seen the other posts on this issue, but none of them list a solution that works for me.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Error Code 0x8007000d
Config Source -1: 0:

UPDATE:

Here are some notes on what I checked:
1) Permissions via Process Monitor.  The config file is being opened correctly.
2) .Net version - Tried multiple settings
3) Integrated vs classic pipeline
4) change enabled 32 bit to true
5) I have not tried **Aspnet_regiis.exe** yet because the other sites on the new box work fine.

Next I'm going to try & comment out various items in the config file

Comment: Look in the error logs, they will have a more detailed message

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue!  The issue was the following line in web.config.  I found this by commenting various things out in web.config until the site worked.  But why is this line an issue on my new 2008 box with IIS 7.5?  What isn't installed or configured?

Update:

This was the line I commented out.  Could this have been related to IIS Feature Delegation?  If config settings in the `<system.webServer>` element are causing this error then Feature Delegation settings could be the problem.

```
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000"/>
```

Comment: Include the offending line for the rest of us?

Answer (score 5):

run->cmd

run "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"

Run this command as a Administrator

Answer (score 4):

You might have used the incorrect asp.net version. please check which version is selected from the iis application pool.

Comment: You may repair asp.net installation on IIS using Aspnet_regiis.exe - [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

you probebly change your NT password.
Enter to IIS right click on your application -> manage application -> advanched Setting -> physical path credentials.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please check this topic for possible answer:
[How do I resolve “HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error” on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0/9495430#9495430)
Answer that is not marked as resolution helped to me. I was missing: [Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was solved by running VS2017 in admin mode.