# Web api is giving error on passing * as the input value to the api method parameter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net mvc web api and i have this method

```
     [HttpGet]
    public  LoginResult AuthenticateOnlineBookingUser(String userName,String password)
    {

         //My Code

    }
```

The problem is  that when i pass (*) as input value to the parameter  (password)
i receieve this error but on other inputs it is working perfectly

**A potentialy dangerous Request.Path.value was detected from client(*)**

Thanks in advance

Note:My client side is written in angular js

i tried this solution as well [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client/6026291#6026291)  but it is not working for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: one more thing i have a password that contains * i cannot override this value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the options for invalid characters. You can do this in your web.config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026291/548997).

Comment: when i add these inside my web config
 <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 <pages validateRequest="false" />  my application gave error

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

  The configuration section 'httpRuntime' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: @HassanTariq You put that inside the `<system.web></system.web>` section, right?

Comment: Wild. I have no idea what is causing that. Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589905/http-error-500-19-in-iis-8-when-system-web-configuration-is-present-in-apphost-c) help at all?

Comment: Actually my application is running on visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Use url encoder to encode the request before sending it to server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved my problem by changing my **GET** request to **POST** request The problem was with query string  in Order to solve it with **GET** Request i have to make some changes to my query string in order to make it work but