# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net

I got this problem after deploying my web package to IIS:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

```
Config Source:


119:     </modules>
120:     <handlers>
121:       <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Scenario 7 on this page [Troubleshooting HTTP 500.19 Errors in IIS 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx), it looks pretty much identical to your error message.

One of the key points I think is the following:

> This usually indicates that ASP.NET is either not installed or has corrupted/incomplete installation because installation of asp.net unlocks that section. Hence if this is the case, one should install asp.net feature from Server Manager (Under Web Server Role in Windows Server 2008 and in Program Features-> Application server in Vista/Windows7). This KB929772 talks about the ASP.NET installation failure reason.

If you're just doing this on your local desktop IIS rather than on a server you may possibly need to use aspnet_regiis to reregister .NET with IIS, although I'm not guaranteeing that will work to unlock the section.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

And the problem was (holy moly):

- On my Local-development IIS I added new MIME type for my site.
- New MIME type was automatically added to my web.config (under *system.webServer* section). **I didn't noticed that**.
- When I published the app to the production server - everything (loading scripts/css/images/etc.) stopped working. (*500.19 - Internal Server Error*)
- After digging more into the problem - I finally saw the exception-msg: **Duplicate MIME type**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error.  I googled for hours. I tried all kind of suggestions.  After hours of frustration, it turned out that I only had an extra double quote in my cshtml file.  I removed the quote and everything worked again.  So error is misleading.  I post this in case somebody else runs into the same problem.