# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007052e

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7, virtual-directory

I copied an MVC project from another development pc to my laptop and tried to deploy it on the laptop which gave this error. The user account password was changed recently prior to this error. I tried tinkering around with the app pool permissions for the root folders with no effect. Any ideas? I am stuck.

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information

**Module**         IIS Web Core
**Notification**   Unknown
**Handler** Not yet determined
**Error Code**  0x8007052e
**Config Error**    Can not log on locally to C:\inetpub\wwwroot as user {MY ACCOUNT} with virtual directory password
**Config File** \?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\ASP.NET v4.0\ASP.NET v4.0.config
**Requested URL**   `http://localhost:80/hts`
**Physical Path**
**Logon Method**    Not yet determined
**Logon User**  Not yet determined

**Config Source**

```
145: <application path="/" applicationPool="ASP.NET v4.0">
146:  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" userName="{MY ACCOUNT}" password="[enc:AesProvider:{etc etc etc}:enc]" />
147: </application>
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling visual studio and eventually got everything working.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (Start > Run > type "inetmgr").
2. Using the navigation pane on the left, browse to Sites > Default Web Site.
3. Right-click on Default Web Site and select Manage Web Site > Advanced Settings.
4. Set the Physical Path Credentials field to Application user (you must enter user and password).
5. Click OK and then OK again.
6. Right-click on Default Web Site and select Manage Web Site > Restart to refresh the changes that were just made.
7. At this point you should be able to reload the page in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Select the site. Default Web site in my case and click "Basic Settings..."
3. This opens the Edit Site dialog.Click "Connect as".
4. In the Connect As dialog, click Set and provide the new password in the Set Credentials dialog.
5. Come back to Edit Site dialog and click "Test Settings..."
6. Once the connections succeeds, you should be able to successfully open the site in your browser.