# http error 500.19 - internal server error iis 0x8007052e IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

i am trying to host web site in IIS but showing error

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x8007052e
Config Error    Can not log on locally to C:\Users\admin\Desktop\WebSite3 as user admin-PC with virtual directory password
Config File Unavailable (Config Isolation)
Requested URL   http://localhost:8039/Default.aspx
Physical Path   
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
```

i am hosting 1st time...how to solve this.....

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918709/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-0x8007052e - it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the site outside from your user folder. Then check security settings for the new folder and grant read permissions to application pool's user. It is usually ok giving read permissions to IIS_IUSRS group. Also you can try [this approach](http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/) out.