# ASP.NET & MVC3 & IIS7 HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I'm trying to deployed my ASP.NET MVC3 Application but when I run it with IIS 7 (passing by Browse *:80(http)), i get this error message :
http://hpics.li/4dc7c93

After that, I tried to give to my Web.config and to the folder of my project all the permissions for the user "IIS_IUSRS" and for my other users but I get a blank page with no errors messages or anything else.

In my Server Manager, I've checked if "HTTP Errors" and "HTTP Redirection" were installed and it's the case.

More, I've checked my Event Viewer and I've seen this error : http://hpics.li/1ee5563. I don't know if this have a link with my problem.

For information, my Application Pool is DefaultAppPool using .NET Framework 4 and I'm working with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, IIS7 and .NET Framework 4.

Do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem ? I'm totally stuck  :/

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a bunch of issues. See possible duplicate at [Web Application Problems (web.config errors) HTTP 500.19 with IIS7.5 and ASP.NET v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808680/)

[Try enabling 32 bit apps in the application pool settings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196191/694325) This is what I'm guessing the problem is but as you can see there are a whole bunch of answers, have you tried them all? Sorry that this is not a real answer.

Comment: I've tried all the answers in your link but nothing change, I've always my blank page without even one error :/ If I had a description of the error which appears when I run my website, this could help me, but I have nothing... Maybe that it comes from a config file like in the Web.config of my application or in the inetpub/config, or from the applicationHost.config...Idk..