# HTTP Error 500.19 in c# IIS

Tags: iis-7

i am getting error as

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the FAQ.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this URL specifically about .19's

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx