# Http error 500.19 in iis

Tags: http, iis

In iis when i try to browse the distributor i got HTTP error 500.19
Error code0X80070021
config source:

```
84  </modules>
 85 </handlers> 
86 <remove name="webservicehandlerfactory-integrated>
```

.Pls help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

your question is in complete
according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055
the problem is in code(server side)

Server Error in Application "application name"
HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error 
HRESULT: 0x80070021
Description of HRESULT
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
please give complete code....