# IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I recently had to reformat my laptop and ever since I did I can't get IIS to work correctly. Ive given it all the same permissions it needs. I set it up the same way I did before the reformat, which is why I'm so confused that I can't get it wo rking.

When running my asp .net page, I get the follow error

IIS HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Error Code - 0x800700b7

Config Source:

```
14             <files>
   15:                 <add value="index.aspx" />
   16:             </files>
```

When I comment out those 3 lines in my Web.config file I get a different 404 error
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Here is a screenshot of the original error

[image]

I have defined the index.aspx as the default document. However, I'm still getting a 404 error. WHen i try to right click and browse the site, I get a 404 which makes me think the index.aspx file isnt in the right location. But Its in the root and I can verify the by 'right clicking' and 'explore'

Here is a screen shot to show what I'm talking about

[image: IIS]

Comment: well it says you are adding a duplicate value, so skip those lines. you need to set your website to run index.aspx as your start page if page is not specified. try navigating to **http://localhost:80/index.aspx** does it work?

Comment: This does not work. It gives me a 404. I already set index.aspx to run as my start page

Comment: Are you sure index.aspx is in the web folder?

Comment: also, is your website the default website? or is it not? (localhost:80/myCustomWebsite/index.aspx)

Comment: The 500.19 error may be due to because you are having a similar entry at a higher level configuration file... It could be at server level or website. The solution would be to do a `<remove value="index.aspx" />` (before the `<add .../>` ) but I'm not exactly sure this works with just value. I always use `<remove name='NameIHaveGiven'/>`

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error][1]. Hope this helps...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go to IIS Manager, select your website on the left, and find the "Default Document" :**

[image]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**there you can add pages that will run DIRECTLY from the root folder of the website.**

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[image]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**if you want your start page to be located in a folder, you need to create one of the files above in the root folder of the website, and redirect onload to your custom start page**

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Since you get error 404 it means that you use the wrong address. Try right clicking your website in the iis manager, choose manage and browse. See if you get it to work this way. Also, your index.aspx must be located in the websites root folder, not a subdirectory

Comment: Hmmm. When I right click and try to browse i get the 404 error. So that must be the issue. However, the index.aspx is in the root folder and I have defined it as the default document. So I dont know what the issue is

Comment: Can you tell me the exact address it puts in your browser when you click browse? Also, is it possible that you forgot to redeploy your website after creatin the index.aspx? (Im sorry for the question but i have to consider all options)

Comment: When I click browse the exact URL it goes to is 'localhost'
Also no I havent forgotten. It's ok. I'm fully convinced this isnt working because of something stupid I forgot

Comment: Do you have multiple websites? Try deactivating all of them and leaving only this one for debugging purposes. Also, ctrl+f5 your website in visual studio, does it work? And what page you get first?

Comment: No I dont. I only run one site through IIS at a time. Also it runs perfectly fine in visual studio. And the page I get first is whatever page I run ctrl+f5 on.

Comment: according to your new pictures, it seems you have some sort of an issue with the web.config, did it fail to synchronize?

Comment: I actually figured it out. I didnt have the correct version of asp .net installed. I reconfigured it and now I'm good. I will accept your answer since it got me on the right path.