# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a local copy of a web site that I know has a valid web.config file, it runs in production and in VIsual Studio 2013. It is running on .net version 4.0. I am getting the dreaded "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error". There is weird info in the config source section of the error page:

Config Source

-1: 
    ***0:***

Anyone ever see this one before and have any ideas how to resolve it? App Pool is set correctly and I checked permissions on the folder and added Everyone with full rights.

Thanks!

Comment: could it be that you are using IIS Express on your local machine while using IIS in production?

Comment: I don't think that should matter, I have another site running locally that works in IIS 7.5

Comment: Is this the production site, or are you running it from visual studio using your localhost?

Comment: The web.config file maybe read only...you may want to check that...this error is telling you it can't access the web.config file

Comment: Yeah I already did that and the same error is occurring..

Comment: I am publishing it to my local IIS server from Visual Studio where it runs successfully.

Comment: So it's running successfully now? Or are you getting this 500.19, because I wouldn't say getting a 500.19 error constitutes "running successfully"

Comment: With so little information it is difficult to diagnose what your issue is but it seems to be something related to accessing your web.config file.  Any additional information would help.

Comment: Yeah that is what I think too, I have checked the permissions on the folder, I even created a folder and moved it there but no luck. I do see that everytime I uncheck Read-Only it reverts back to the setting and it's greyed out.

Comment: Have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091640/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error/29032247#29032247. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 5):

There are many sources of this error – I seem to have hit most of them :((

This applies to Win Server 2008 R2 64 bit SP1 & IIS 7.5.

**.NET version different between Web-App & assigned Application Pool**

Generally, the web-app .NET version is specified in the Web.config file

```
...
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
...
```

The .NET version of the app-pool assigned to this application must be compatible

To get the app-pool that is assigned to a web-app

```
IIS Manager > [web-app] > Basic Settings > Application Pool
```

To set the .NET version of the app-pool

```
IIS Manager > Application Pools > [app-pool-name] > Basic Settings > .NET Framework Version
```

Generally, there are only two choices .NET 2.0.50727 and .NET 4.0.30319

We have installed .NET 4.6.1 - (4.6.01055) but in IIS, only the above versions are shown.

**Web-App Physical Path set to a Mapped Folder**

The physical path associated with the web-app must be a UNC path - not a mapped path.

```
IIS Manager > [web-app] > Basic Settings > Physical Path
```

this works:

```
\\[server-name]\share
```

this fails:

```
M:\share
```

The reason is that mapped network drives only exist in your session, not the session that IIS is running.

**Web-App Physical Path Access Rights**

The user-account set in the app-pool must have sufficient access rights to access the web-app physical path.

This user-account must be given these permissions (with inherited rights for sub-folders):

- Modify
- Read & Execute
- List Folder Contents
- Read
- Write

IIS 7.5 has a built-in virtual account ‘ApplicationPoolIdentity’ that can be used for all app-pools. When this built-in account is associated with an app-pool, IIS creates a new unique user-account for that app-pool.

If this default account mechanism is used, then the associated account on the IIS server must be given permissions via Windows Explorer using this format:

```
IIS AppPool\<app-pool-name>
```

[image]

Note that the IIS server (where the app-pool resides) must be selected in 'Locations...' with the app-pool name in the above format (case-insensitive).
When you click 'Check Names', the unique app-pool account will then be resolved and can then be assigned the correct permissions.

Because each app-pool must have a unique name, the associated account is also unique.

Rather than use the IIS built-in accounts, another option is to run the app-pool under a dedicated service account. Using a service account means that the password does not expire (among other things).
The service account must be given the above permissions on the root folder.

A normal user account can also be used but this is not recommended because of password expiry and the associated access rights need to be carefully set.

**App-Pool Account Password Changed/Expired**

For the app-pool user-account, if this password has changed or expired, you need to explicitly updated the password in IIS

```
IIS Manager > Application Pools > [app-pool-name] > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity
```

This does not apply if you use the IIS built-in virtual account ‘ApplicationPoolIdentity’ - the created account does not have a password. Another reason to use the IIS virtual account mechanism.

**URL Rewrite Module not installed**

If the web-app uses rewrite rules, the URL rewrite module must be installed

Rewrite rules may be specified in the Web.config file

```
...
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Timesheets Index Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="Timesheets/Index" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="Timesheets/Entries" />
    </rule>
...
```

**ASP.NET not registered in IIS**

Depending on the order in which IIS and .NET 4 are installed / updated, it may be necessary to re-register ASP.NET with IIS.

To check, in a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

aspnet_regiis -lv
```

This should give something like

```
...
2.0.50727.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

Here, .NET 2 is registered for 64 bit apps and .NET 4 is registered for both 32 & 64 bit apps.

If your target framework & 32/64 bit config is not in the list:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your appPool is set to "Integrated"

look at here the diferences between modes:

[What is the difference between 'classic' and 'integrated' pipeline mode in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716049/what-is-the-difference-between-classic-and-integrated-pipeline-mode-in-iis7)

Comment: Yeah I did that as well. It's a weird issue.